# cannot connect to mosquitto using esp32 when device more than one

Tags: mqtt, esp32, mosquitto

i am trying to connect to my broker on vps on esp32 using pubsubclient + tinygsm library. at first it run well but after i try to connect with the second esp32 it connect-disconnect-reconnect frequently. but if i remove one of them it runs well. when it does the display error log like this on
AT Command on esp32

```
Connecting to broker success
/00008CEAC108B764
MQTT NOT CONNECTED ===
-3 try again in 5 seconds
Connecting to broker success
/00008CEAC108B764
MQTT NOT CONNECTED ===
-3 try again in 5 seconds
Connecting to broker success
```

on the mosquitto logs it display

```
1690639873: Client 0000C49B6015B80C disconnected due to malformed packet.
1690639874: New connection from 114.127.245.13:47135 on port 1883.
1690639874: New client connected from 114.127.245.13:47135 as 0000C49B6015B80C (p2, c1, k15).
1690639875: Client 0000C49B6015B80C disconnected due to malformed packet.
1690639875: New connection from 114.127.245.13:47428 on port 1883.
```

and it also happen when i am using wifi connection with "error host unreachable"

i have try to connect to mosquitto broker with another devices such as mymqtt on android and mqttx on windows and it run well also. so at first i think the problem is the code on device. but i change the broker with public broker like broker.hivemq and it works with multiple device.
by the way this is the library and it version on my esp32.

- bakercp/CRC32@^2.0.0
- vshymanskyy/TinyGSM@^0.11.7
- bblanchon/ArduinoJson@^6.21.3
- mandulaj/PZEM-004T-v30@^1.1.2
- vshymanskyy/StreamDebugger@^1.0.1
- knolleary/PubSubClient@^2.8

hope someone know how to solve this other than change the broker.

Comment: Edit the question to show the code